# What equation represents the line that passes through $(–6, 7)$ and $(–3, 6)$?

Tags: algebra-precalculus

Please help with my algebra.

> Which equation represents the line that passes through $(–6, 7)$ and $(–3, 6)$?

Comment: no :( I have not

Comment: what does the word gradient mean to you?

Comment: hint: this line has at least 3 points $(-6,7)$, $(-3,6)$ and $(x,y)$. Combine that with the fact that the slope is defined as $\frac{\Delta y}{\Delta x}$.

Comment: Entering "equation of line through two points" into Google would give you an explanation, and spare from this downvote.

Answer (score 2):

Well you want a line in the form $\color{red}{y = mx + c}$ where $m$ is the slope of the line and $c$ is the $y$-intercept.

$$ m = \frac{y_2-y_1}{x_2-x_1} = \frac{6-7}{-3--6} = \frac{-1}{3}$$

Now you can take one point say for example  $(-3,6)$and assume that you don't know the other one (after you got the slope)  and now you can use it to get the equation of the line as follows (Just using the same formula of the slope, but now with different unknown)

$$ \frac{y - 6}{x - (-3)} = \frac{-1}{3}$$

and so you have $3(y - 6) = -(x+3) \implies 3y - 18 = -x -3$ and so $$3y = -x + 15$$ and so $$\color{red}{y = \frac{-1}{3}x + 5}$$

with $m = \frac{-1}{3}$ and the y-intercept is equal to $5$

Comment: Some of the teX didn't come through correctly.  Probably just some kind of spacing error?

Comment: the answers are listed like this y = –x + 9

y = –x + 5

y = –3x – 11y

y = –3x + 25

Comment: When you say $(-6,7)$, is that $(x,y)$ or $(y,x)$?  What @alkabary has is correct for $(x,y)$.

Comment: it's (x,y)  ....

Comment: Double check that you have the right numbers and/or right question?

Comment: @RobertShort Ok I did a minor mistake , it is fixed now

Comment: = –1/3x + 9

y = –1/3x + 5

y = –3x – 11y

y = –3x + 25

Comment: only options I have

Comment: @paula yes I got y = –1/3x + 5

Comment: okay thank you so much

Comment: The point-slope form of the equation of the line that passes through (–5, –1) and (10, –7) is y + 7 = -2/5 (x – 10). What is the standard form of the equation for this line?

Comment: @paula You should follow the same procedure I made in the solution. First get the slope $m$ and then use one of the point to get the equation

Answer (score 1):

If you want a line in the equation form $$y-y_1 = m(x -x_1)$$ where $m$ is the slope of the line, you can take $(x_1,y_1)=(-3,6)$ and $(x_2,y_2)=(-6,7)$, we have

$$ m = \frac{y_2-y_1}{x_2-x_1} = \frac{7-6}{-6+3} = \frac{-1}{3}.$$

So,

$$y-6=\frac{-1}{3}(x+3)$$

that implies

$$y=\frac{-x}{3}+5.$$